# Abstract external APIs

Tags: api, typescript, interface

I'm using an external API fetch and then display data.

To be flexible, I want to decouple the API completely from my code and want to work with self-defined data structures.

Here a brief graphical overview:
[image]

To make the task a little more concret here an example:

Let's assume the data is about people:

API v1.0 spits `{"name": "John"}` out whereas API v1.1 spits `{"pName": "John"}` out.

To prevent that this minor change would break my code I want have two interfaces internally: one for a parser (which parses the API response) and one for as a structure for the data itself:

```
interface IPersonDataStructure {
    name : string;
}

interface IPersonDataParser {
    parse(input: string) : IPersonDataStructure;
}
```

Then I want to have a class that combines the parser with the data structure:

```js
// This class uses any parser which implements IPersonDataParser
// And uses IPersonDataStructure 
class Person {

}
```

And this is where I'm stuck! I don't know how to combine the two together!

I don't like the idea of an instance per Person's instance:

```js
let aPerson = new Person(new Parser(data))
```

Because the parser should be stateless (e.g. like a function).

The problem is TypeScript didn't allow me to do that with classes:

```js
class Parser implements IPersonDataParser {
    static public function parse(data : string) : IPersonDataStructure {
        return {...}
    }
}

class Person {
    private _data : IPersonDataStructure;

    constructor(data : string, parser : IPersonDataParser) {
        this._data = parser.parse(data)
    }
}
```

Callbacks are an option but only if I can validate their signature.

For example this does not validate correctly:

```js
type PersonDataParser = (data : string) => IPersonDataStructure;

// Whoops.. argument is missing!
let aParser = () => {
    return {...}
}

let aPerson = new Person('data', aParser)
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are trying to address here?

Comment: I want to implement the described functionality in a clean way

Comment: This isn't really the type of question stackoverflow handles. Maybe try the code review stack exchange website? Here it's going to generate a lot of opinion based solutions. :)

Comment: that being said.. I would say this is pretty clean: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Parser%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(data%3A%20string)%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20PersonData%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20data%3A%20PersonData)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20aParser%3A%20Parser%3CPersonData%3E%20%3D%20(data)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20data%3B%20%2F%2F%20actual%20implementation%20here%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20aPerson%20%3D%20new%20Person(aParser('data'))%3B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can have a static method and have it satisfy the interface - all using type inference and structural types, like this:

```
interface IPersonDataStructure {
    name : string;
}

interface IPersonDataParser {
    parse(input: string) : IPersonDataStructure;
}

class Parser {
    public static parse(data : string) : IPersonDataStructure {
        return { name: 'Steve' };
    }
}

class Person {
    private _data : IPersonDataStructure;

    constructor(data : string, parser : IPersonDataParser) {
        this._data = parser.parse(data)
    }
}

let person = new Person('', Parser);
```

I would probably prefer a design where the `Person` just represented a person and didn't have to take in a mapper in order to be constructed. More like this...

```
interface IPersonDataStructure {
    name : string;
}

class Person {
    constructor(private data : IPersonDataStructure) {
    }
}

class PersonMapper {
    public static map(data: string): Person {
        return new Person({
            name: 'Steve'
        });
    }
}

let person = PersonMapper.map('...');
```

If your version number is part of the data, you can use that to determine the correct mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an adapter which will check which of the two properties were returned from the API?

```
interface ApiResponse {
    name?: string;
    pName?: string;
}

class Person {
    public name: string;

    constructor (name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class ApiResponseAdapter {
    private getName(response: ApiResponse): string {
        if (response.pName) return pName;
        if (response.name) return name;

        // if neither are set, return null
        return null;
    }

    public adapt(response: ApiResponse): Person {
        let name = this.getName(response);

        if (name === null) {
            throw new Error("Invalid name for response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }

        return new Person(name);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could have a base `ApiResponse` interface which has implementations to handle the behaviour:

```
interface ApiResponse {
    name: string;
}

class Api_V1_0_Response implements ApiResponse {
    public name: string;

    constructor (json: any) {
        this.name = json["name"];
    }
}

class Api_V1_1_Response implements ApiResponse {
    public name: string;

    constructor (json: any) {
        this.name = json["pName"];
    }
}

class Person {
    public name: string;

    constructor (name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class ApiResponseAdapter {
    public adapt(response: ApiResponse): Person {
        return new Person(
            response.name
        );
    }
}
```

Or go a step further and have an abstract `BaseApiResponse` class which is extended by the other two:

```
interface ApiResponse {
    name: string;
}

abstract class BaseApiResponse implements ApiResponse {
    public name: string;

    constructor (nameKey: string, json: any) {
        this.name = json[nameKey];
    }
}

class Api_V1_0_Response extends BaseApiResponse {   
    constructor (json: any) {
        super("name", json);
    }
}

class Api_V1_1_Response extends BaseApiResponse {   
    constructor (json: any) {
        super("pName", json);
    }
}

class Person {
    public name: string;

    constructor (name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class ApiResponseAdapter {
    public adapt(response: ApiResponse): Person {
        return new Person(
            response.name
        );
    }
}
```